# I run sudo g++ main.cpp, but it doesn't run the program

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm trying to run the program from the terminal on macOS. I run this:

```
sudo g++ main.cpp
```

but it just "skips" the command and doesn't build the program, just like this

```
101:nrprim mac$ sudo g++ main.cpp 
101:nrprim mac$
```

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool divizibil(int n, int i){
    if (n%i==0) return 1; else return 0;
}

int numarDivizori(int n){
    int i, c=0;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        if (divizibil(n,i)) c++;
    return c;
}

void prim(int n){
    int c=0;
    c=numarDivizori(n);
    if (c>2) cout<<"Numarul nu e prim"; else
        cout<<"Numarul e prim\n";

}
int main() {
    int n;
    cout<<"n=";
    cin>>n;
    prim(n);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that it would output

> n=

and just wait for the input

Comment: It _does_ build the program. You need to run it afterwards though.

Comment: [`sudo g++ main.cpp  && a.out`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d74a9dddc316f82) should fix your problem.

Comment: Caution!   You probably should not be using 'sudo' for compiling a) "g++ main.cpp" nor for running b) "./main" (or perhaps "./a.out").  'sudo' allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user, by default the superuser.  As superuser, you can mess up a lot of file priviledges, etc.

Comment: Your code compiled (g++ main.cpp) on my Lubuntu machine, and when I ran it (./main), it worked just like you expected, i.e. does nothing but prompt for n.

Answer (score 2):

It does build the program, you should see it as `a.out` in the same directory. If you'd like to name it something else, use the `-o` option like this. You can run the program by simply running either this `a.out` or the named executable.

`c++ src.cpp -o myoutput`

By the way, I don't think you need the `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

G++ **compiles** your code, which is different from **executing** your code.  If you type **ls** into the terminal you should see the new file, which was created by G++ by compiling your source file.  If you run *that* file, then you should see your program execute.

**Compiling** is taking your source code and basically translating it from one language to another.  In this case G++ is compiling your code from C++ to a binary language that the machine will understand.  Once compiled, the result is saved to a file.  That file is often an executable that you can run by typing it's name into the terminal.  For example, if the executable file is **a**, you'd type **./a** (the **./** tells the terminal that the file is in the current directory).

EDIT: Also, As others have said, you probably shouldn't be using sudo for something like this as it's most likely not necessary and can be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it in one line like this:

```
g++ file cpp && ./a.out
```

or to delete `a.out` after you run it:

```
g++ file.cpp && ./a.out && rm a.out
```

`g++ file.cpp` compiles, links and creates executable `a.out`. To run `a.out` you simply put `./a.out`. `rm a.out` in second line removes `a.out`. `&&` means if preceding command succeeds continue with the next.

One more note **no need for `sudo` when compiling**